# Opening post in popup by clicking on it's shorter version

Tags: php, wordpress, popup, fancybox

Hi I need to create a simple popup function for wordpress site.

I got loop that is running and showing posts properly. Post when clicked should appear in popup. What I;ve got so far. Apart from adding fancybox to do it's job.

```
<a class="modalbox" rel="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" href=" http://localhost/makijaz/?page_id=12">
     <article> ...Wordpress post </article>
```

I got the one beneath from other thread, but it's not working.

```
 $(".modalbox").on("click", function() {
       var postId = $(this).prop("rel");
       $(this).fancybox();

    });
```

href in  is directing to page with template with other loop. Need to Simply gram PostID (it's in rel of an ) and put it into other loop for showing in popup.

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Ajax Post Handler
*/
?>
<?php
    $post = get_post($_GET['id']);
?>
<?php if ($post) : ?>
    <?php setup_postdata($post); ?>
    <div class="whatever">
        <h2 class="entry-title"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hopefully, I've made myself clear.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your page template doesn't have a get_header and get_footer so in your example scripts won't load.

```
<?php
  /*
  Template Name: Your Temp Name
  */
get_header(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the ***post id*** so `$post = get_post($_GET['id']);` can fetch it, you could try

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".modalbox").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var postId = $(this).prop("rel");
        $.fancybox.open({
            href: this.href + "&amp;id=" + postId,
            type: "ajax"
        });
    });
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zUXHy/)**